# How to transfer files between two server accounts

Tags: sftp

I have two server accounts (tow student user accounts of same university Linux server). I would like to transfer files between them using SFTP command.

I tried to login the first user account using `$ ssh user1@server_host` Then, I tried to connect the second user account and access files I want to transfer using `$ sftp user2@server_host:/path/to/files`
Next I would like to get files from user2 to user1 using `$ get /path/to/files/file.txt`

But `sftp user2@server_host:/path/to/files` shows the error: `ssh: connect to host gw.cse.cuhk.edu.hk port 22: Connection refused`

I did Google search about how to use SFTP. But they are all about transferring from local to server and server to local. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
Can the "user1" host resolve the hostname of the "user2" machine ?
`user1@server_host1:$ nslookup server_host2` : you can use this command to check if he can resolve the hostname.

If that works out I would check the network permissions to see if you have the rights to access the "server_host2" using port 22.
`user1@server_host1:$ telnet server_host2 22`
If you get some output reasembling the following then SSH is authorized between the 2 hosts:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. For ```user1@server_host1:$ nslookup server_host2```, it can resolve the hostname. (Actually, server_host1 and server_host2 is the same host. i.e *gw.cse.cuhk.edu.hk*) But ```user1@server_host1:$ telnet server_host2 22``` shows error: ```telnet: connect to address 137.189.90.235: Connection refused```

Comment: It looks like you don't have the network rights to access the server_host2 from within server-host1. I should contact your network administrator to expose the port 22 between the 2 hosts. Before that, could you checkthat the sshd.service is running ? (`user@server_host2:$ systemctl status sshd`)

Comment: @ Thanks Jonathan P! sshd.service is running. As second answer said, after I login user1, I tried ```$sftp user2@linux10:path/to/files/file.txt``` instead of ```$ sftp user2@gw.cse.cuhk.edu.hk:path/to/files/file.txt```. And it works! What is linux10? is it a localhost?

Comment: My question may be edited to "How to transfer files between two user accounts in the same server".

Answer (score 0):

If `user1` and `user2` are on the same `server_host`, you could try the SFTP command in the form:

```
sftp user2@localhost:/path/to/files
```

The first element of the hostname `gw.cse.cuhk.edu.hk` is `gw` which usually means *gateway*, suggesting that it might be the host designed to accept connections from outside the university.

That name, and the IP associated with it, might only be accessible from outside the university network, and once you have logged in with `ssh user1@server_host`, you are now entering commands effectively *inside* the university network.

Perhaps you should use some other name (maybe something like `nile.cse.cuhk.edu.hk` or `myhome1.cse.cuhk.edu.hk`?) to access the server host from inside the university network? Or perhaps `gw.cse.cuhk.edu.hk` is actually a SSH proxy that sends each user to whatever university-internal host they have been assigned to, and `user1` and `user2` are not on the same physical server after all. This is something only the IT support of the university could answer with certainty.

Comment: Thank you so much telcoM. ```sftp user2@localhost:/path/to/files``` works! In my case, it is ```sftp user2@linux10:/path/to/files```. As you say, ```gw.cse.cuhk.edu.hk``` is for student outside university. ```sftp user2@gw.cse.cuhk.edu.hk:/path/to/files``` will not work.

Comment: By the way, would you please tell me is ```linux10``` a ***localhost***?

Comment: `localhost` is a special name associated with the special IP address 127.0.0.1, which always refers *to the same computer it's used on*. So every computer that uses TCP/IP can (or should be able to) use that name (and that IP address) to refer back to itself, even if all real network connections are down. So, on `linux10` the name `localhost` refers to `linux10`, on `linux11` it refers to `linux11` and so on.